# What is the difference between a procedure-oriented and a problem-oriented programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

This is one of the questions given to us an assignment and I've tried to search for this on the internet but didn't get the required answers. Would be great if examples are provided too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to begin your search with [domain specific languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language):

> A domain-specific language (DSL) is a type of programming language or specification language in software development and domain engineering dedicated to a particular problem domain, a particular problem representation technique, and/or a particular solution technique.

I've never heard of a problem-oriented programming language, but a DSL sounds similar to what I imagine a problem-oriented programming language might be.

Answer (score -3):

Procedure oriented programming language describes the procedure of the program. The importance is given to the procedure. These type of language are difficult to learn. These languages uses files for storing and retrieving data. In comparison to problem oriented language, the codes are difficult to understand and to debug. 
Example : C.

In similar way, in case of problem oriented language the importance is given to data. These language uses database to store and retrieve data. The codes are in natural language so its easy to understand. These programming language just describes what to do. Moreover, the system knows what to do.

I tried my best to make this easier to understand :)